# Word for a modified version of a quote

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Allow me to explain: There is a famous ***quote*** from the movie [shining](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081505/)

> "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy"

I can also ***paraphrase*** it: *Jack was dull because he didn't play enough*.

My question is, what if I intentionally modify the original quote and turn it into the following?

> All work and no play makes **Pouya** a dull boy

This is neither a quote nor a paraphrase. Is there any word for these kinds of phrases?

Comment: I think it still is a paraphrase:   The adaptation or alteration of a text or quotation to serve a different purpose from that of the original. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paraphrase

Answer (score 5):

A [snowclone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone) is a well-known phrase with "blanks" that can be filled in. For example:

- "_____ is the new _____"
- "_____ is my middle name"
- "The _____ to end all _____"

"All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy" is definitely a well-known phrase, so it seems "All work and no play makes _____ a dull boy" qualifies as a snowclone.

Answer (score 0):

It is a paraphrasing, to quote [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paraphrase):

> Express the meaning of (something written or spoken) using different words, especially to achieve greater clarity

You have clarified it, changing *jack* (i.e. any man) to your own name.

But an another name for such use is *snowclone*,  which is where you take a well worn phrase and substitute words to better fit your meaning.

Comment: But when paraphrasing, shouldn't one remain conceptually honest with the original quote?

Comment: In your example I believe you are remaining so. But yes, you should remain conceptually honest.

Comment: Does Oxford give any definitions or citations for usages which adapt the original phraseology to express a meaning which is *different from* the original?